# Convert two column list to a table in excel

Tags: excel

I have a two column list of countries with corresponding cities:

| Country | State |
| --- | --- |
| India | Andaman and Nicobar Islands |
| India | Andhra Pradesh |
| India | Arunachal Pradesh |
| Indonesia | Aceh |
| Indonesia | Bali |
| Indonesia | Bangkaâ€“Belitung Islands |
| Iran | Ä€zÌ„ÄrbÄyjÄn-e GharbÄ« |
| Iran | ÄªlÄm |
| Iran | Alborz |

I want to convert unique Countries in column1 to headers of a table and all States in column2 to appear under respective Countries headers.

| India | Indonesia | Iran |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Andaman and Nicobar Islands | Aceh | Ä€zÌ„ÄrbÄyjÄn-e GharbÄ« |
| Andhra Pradesh | Bali | ÄªlÄm |
| Arunachal Pradesh | Bangkaâ€“Belitung Islands | Alborz |

What is the quickest way to achieve this if the list is long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Microsoft 365, try below formulas as per attached screenshot-

```
D3=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A2:A10))
D4=FILTER($B$2:$B$10,$A$2:$A$10=D$3)
```

Drag `D4` cell formula to right as per your need.

[image]

Comment: This is quick and simple solution that I couldn't find on the internet. The other solution I found is array formula in D4: {=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$10,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$10=D$3,ROW($B$2:$B$10)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$10))+1),ROWS($D$4:D4))),"")}. I got the exact same results using both solutions. I would like to know what are the differences/exceptions, if any.

Comment: That is for older versions of excel. `FILTER()` function is available on latest version of excel.